# Provide a List of values as search Criteria in Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

I have the implemented Hibernate search and it works fine.

So if i say want to get all employees matching Captain ,i use the following code

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Employee.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.keyword().onFields("name")
                .matching("Captain").createQuery();

        // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
        javax.persistence.Query persistenceQuery = fullTextEntityManager
                .createFullTextQuery(query, Employee.class);

        // execute search
        List<Employee> result = persistenceQuery.getResultList();
        System.out.println("num of employess:" + result);
```

My question is if i want to pass a list of values as search criteria,does hibernate search provide any method to do that.

For example if i want to get employees from a table whose names are similar to either one in the following list [Abhi,Juhi,Joan,Paul,James]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search for multiple possible words in the same field, simply add them all in the matching clause.

```
//search document with storm or lightning in their history
Query luceneQuery = 
    mythQB.keyword().onField("history").matching("storm lightning").createQuery();
```

Check documentation

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.1/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html

Comment: I am guessing we can do fuzzy and wild card search matching multiple values also right ?